# how is the popup displayed on rollover of a thumbnail image designed? Javascript, CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image, thumbnails, rollover

I'm building a photogallery, and as per the requirement, when the mouse rolls over the thumbnail image, a little enlarged version of the thumbnail with details like title of the actual image, size etc.. needs to be displayed on the enlarged image. Note- the enlarged image is displayed only upon rollover, and immediately disappears when the mouse moves out of the area of the thumbnail image. I know this is a really common functionality in most of the photogallery sites out there, and a perfect example being the Yahoo Image Search (see: [Yahoo Image Search](http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=A0PDoYBM3ZlOzj4AEYqLuLkF;_ylu=X3oDMTBvbDQ2Nmh1BHNlYwNpYnV6egRzbGsDaW1nBHBvcwM2Mg--?ei=UTF-8&bz_b=60&bz_n=12&fr2=sfp-buzz&p=Anne%20Hathaway))

Basically, as per the requirement the code needs to be built in Javascript without the use of any libraries like Jquery. So in core JS, the rollover should work.

I know that the onmouseover can do this, but my question is how do ensure that the enlarged image is displayed appropriately (as in, to the right of the thumbnail when enough space is available, or else to the left/above/top of the thumbnail, as the spacing constraint may be?

Also, how is the "new page" that pops up on rollover designed (well, not exactly a new page, but just an unobtrusive popup)?

Any directions on how to go about is much appreciated. Note - I know libraries ease out this thing, but as I said it needs to be done in core JS, even if the fading-in/fade-out looks crude.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple, straightforward implementation without 3rd party libraries or Ajax. This is far from production quality, but might help you get started.

The main "trick" is, that the image lies in a container, that has the CSS "overflow:hidden"... Then when you rollover, you set the CSS so that it shows the overflow (for example by changing the classname)... In addition the change of the classname also then shows the additional information, that was embedded in the page all along, but was set to "display:none" before...

Hope that this helps.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container{
                position: relative;
                display:block;
                width: 150;
                height: 150px;
                float:left;
                margin:5px;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .container .popup{
                position: absolute;
                display:block;
                width: 150;
                height: 150px;
                overflow: hidden;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .container img{
                position:relative;
            }

            .container .footer{
                display:none;
            }

            .containerOpen{
                position: relative;
                display:block;
                width: 150;
                height: 150px;
                float:left;
                margin:5px;
                 z-index: 20000;
            }

            .containerOpen .popup{
                position: absolute;
                display:block;
                padding: 5px;
                overflow: visible;
                background: #ff0000;
                z-index: 10000;
            }
            .containerOpen img{
                position:relative;
                left: 0px !important;
                top: 0px !important;
            }

            .containerOpen .footer{
                display:block;
                background:#cccccc;
                padding:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="popup">
                <img src="http://ts3.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1290129900246&id=6bfb5f7543719fe92db9edb864a8ea90" />
                <div class="footer">
                    Additional Information goes here.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="popup">
                <img src="http://ts3.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1262145976094&id=358c632c2a4025e850b559ccf1778dff" />
                <div class="footer">
                    Additional Information goes here.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="popup">
                <img src="http://ts2.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1311373591873&id=6c6770a9c21d648841bbd3c47324d848" />
                <div class="footer">
                    Additional Information goes here.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementsByClass = function(classname){
                var itemsfound = [];
                var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
                for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
                    if(elements[i].className == classname){
                        itemsfound.push(elements[i]);
                    }
                }
                return itemsfound;
            }

            window.onload = function () { 
                var containers = document.getElementsByClass('container');
                for (var i in containers){
                    var elContainer = containers[i];
                    var elPopup = elContainer.children[0];
                    var elImg = elPopup.children[0];
                    var elFooter = elPopup.children[1];
                    var width = elImg.offsetWidth;
                    var height = elImg.offsetHeight;
                    var thumbWidth = 150;
                    var thumbHeight = 150;
                    var offsetX = "left:-" + Math.round(0.5*(width-thumbWidth)) + "px; ";
                    var offsetY = "top:-" + Math.round(0.5*(height-thumbHeight)) + "px; ";
                    elImg.setAttribute("style", offsetX + offsetY );

                    elContainer.onmouseover = function(){
                        this.className = 'containerOpen';
                    }

                    elContainer.onmouseout = function(){
                        this.className = 'container';
                    }
                }
            }       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to request the page and append to a div on the current page, with css style position of absolute or relative.  I use this method for one of my gallerys.

- onmouseover of the button or thumb, will fire GetPhoto();toggle('photo');style('photo');
- - **GetPhoto()** will ajax to what ever file has the photo or the photo itself, and hide it in the id="photo" DIV.
- - **toggle()** Will switch the id="photo" DIV tag's visibility to visible
- - **style()** Will switch the id="photo" DIV tag's position to fixed.

TO CONFIGURE: change the file in

> xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR.PAGE.php",true);

to the name of the file you will be using.

---

```
<div id="photo" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <script>
//<![CDATA[
        function GetPhoto(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            // clear element first so it can be reused.
            document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML='';
            document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR.PAGE.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send();          
        }
function toggle(obj) {
    var item = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (item.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        item.style.visibility = 'hidden';    
     }
    else {
        item.style.visibility = 'visible';
     }
}
function style(obj) {
    var item = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (item.style.position == 'fixed') { item.style.position = 'absolute'; }
    else { item.style.position = 'fixed'; }
}
//]]>
    </script>
<button onmouseover="GetPhoto(); toggle('photo'); style('photo');" onmouseout="toggle('photo'); style('photo');">Mouse Over Object</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div with absolute positioning as a container to show the enlarged version. Set the "left" and "top" of the div based on the x & y of the thumbnail. To calculate the positioning of the div, you can use the window's height & width and check if

```
[width of pop-up div] + [left of the div] < [width of the window]
```

Similar thing can be done for the height as well.